# How does React know if a function is a component or not?

Tags: reactjs

In the React [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html), it says function components need to have a class type -

> When React sees an element with a function or class type, it knows to
>   ask that component what element it renders to, given the corresponding
>   props.

```
const Button = ({ children, color }) => ({
  type: 'button',
  props: {
    className: 'button button-' + color,
    children: {
      type: 'b',
      props: {
        children: children
      }
    }
  }
});
```

But in the react-redux [example](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html) by Dan Abramov, his presentational component doesn't have a class type anywhere, so how does React know the below is a component? Is it because it has propTypes?

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'

const Todo = ({ onClick, completed, text }) => (
  <li
    onClick={onClick}
    style={{
      textDecoration: completed ? 'line-through' : 'none'
    }}
  >
    {text}
  </li>
)

Todo.propTypes = {
  onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  completed: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  text: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

export default Todo
```

Answer (score 1):

The first Button example you use is what JSX will eventually transpile to (which is why it looks so different than the second Todo example). Once your Todo component gets run through Babel, that JSX will turn into an object like this,

```
const Todo = ({ onClick, completed, text }) => ({
  type: 'li',
  props: {
    children: text,
    style: {
      textDecoration: completed ? 'line-through' : 'none'
    },
    onClick: onClick
  }
})
```

So, at the end of the day (or transpilation), our Todo component has a "type" property just as the React docs explained. You can find more info here [React Elements vs React Components](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-elements-vs-react-components/)

Answer (score 0):

That's a [stateless component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions%22stateless%20component%22). It's just a function that spits out HTML based on some props.